# Adding links to article category in joomla search results

Tags: search, joomla, hyperlink, categories

In Joomla 2.5, I'm seeking a way to add more Article related features to the search results by modifying the com_search templates. In this case I'm wondering how to include a link to the result's category? The default_results.php page includes the category/section for each returned article but no link to that category. Can it be referenced by the arrow operator?

Additionally, what about other Article features such as the rating and author? Can these be included in search results also?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at creating a template override for the search results you will be limited to the data available.

Looking at the search results `view.html.php` the results array contains a list of objects with the following attributes (*as observed in Eclipse*)

```
stdObj:
- title
- text
- created
- browsernav
- catid
- slug
- href
- section
- count
```

As you can see rating and author are not available to the tmpl, so you would have to modify the search component to get this additional information or use the available information to load the `content` model and extract it yourself.

For linking to a category blog page you could use the `catid` in conjunction with `JRoute` to create a URL to a category blog layout. Something like this could work (*N.B. used multiple lines for readability*):

```
$catURL = 'index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=';
$catURL .= $result->catid;
$catURL = JRoute::_($catURL);
```

Then all you need to do is wrap the line that contains the category (section) in the URL e.g..

```
( <a href="<?php echo $catURL; ?>" ><?php echo $this->escape($result->section); ?></a> )
```

*Please note haven't tried this code just typed it in here...*

**[EDIT]**

com_search (which provides Joomla! search function) uses search plugins to gather results, plugins are used so that different types of content can provide their results...

So, in the Joomla! 2.5 line that means that sub-folders of `/plugins/search/` are loaded by default this includes standard Joomla! content like *contacts*, *content*, *weblink*, etc.  Third party extensions may also provide a search plugin eg. `virtuemart`

To find out what is returned by a particular plugin you will need to look through the relevant file eg. for content `/plugins/search/content/content.php`

Comment: Ok great, that gets me heading in the right direction, I think. I'm still learning how Joomla integrates all these files. Thanks

Comment: Ok, so apparently $result->catid doesn't exist anymore and in looking at view.html.php for com_search I don't see that list of attributes you posted either. Any ideas or is it possible to include catid by hand?

Comment: It does exist - that list came from using Eclipse and inspecting the results object that was returned by a search. You won't find them defined in the view - you have to look at the model and then the plugin to see how results are gathered. I've edited the answer to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Still no. echo $result->catid from default_results.php prints nothing. Interestingly, var_dump($result) also doesn't show it as a key=>value pair but it does turn up embedding in the URL string value for the href key. A var_dump also revealed the catslug key which includes the slug and category id within the same string. Using a substr on that achieved the results I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla 3.3.0 I managed to display the linked category name in the search results this way:

```
<?php
$url = $result->catslug;
$url = str_replace(':', '', $url);
$url = ltrim($url, '0123456789');
?>
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" ><?php echo $this->escape($result->section); ?></a>
```

(However I'm not sure if it's an opimal solution.)